# Executing multiple functions OnPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to execute a function and navigate to the next screen using React-navigation and creating an Axios post

I've already tried combining both function's but It doesn't seem to execute the `createOrder` function

If I run the `createOrder` function alone it does work

```
onPress={
    () => {
        this.createOrder
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Cart', {
            order : this.state.order
        });
    }
}
```

```
 import React from 'react';
  import { 
    View,  
    StyleSheet, 
    Text,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity
 } from 'react-native';
 //Redux
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import { addItemToCart, removeItem } from '../../actions/ProductActionCreators';
//Products
 import Products from '../../components/products/Products';
 // Api Url
 import ApiUrl from '../../helpers/ApiUrl'
 //UI LIBRARY
 import { Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
 import {LinearGradient} from "../../components/LinearGradient";
 import { ButtonGroup } from 'react-native-elements';
 import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
 //AXIOS
 import axios from 'axios';

 export  class ProductsListView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { rows } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        const arrays = Object.values( {rows});
        this.state = {
            arrays,
            filteredProducts: arrays,
            selectedIndex: 2
        };
        this.updateIndex = this.updateIndex.bind(this)
    }

  createOrder () {
    axios.post( ApiUrl + 'api/order/post', {
            code: "4f",
            status: "waiting",
            user_name: "salman", 
            user_id: 1,
            club_id: 1,
        })
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
                order: response.data,
            });
            console.log('created order',this.state.order)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error',error);
    })
  }

    updateIndex (selectedIndex) {
        this.setState({selectedIndex})
    }
    filterAll(){

    }
    filterStrong(){
        this.setState({
            arrays: this.state.arrays[0].products.filter(item => item.type == "strong" )
        })
        console.log(this.state.arrays)
    }
    filterNormal(){

    }
      render() {
        const component1 = () => <Icon
        name="ios-star"
        size={15}
        color="gold"
        />
        const component2 = () => <Icon
        name="ios-beer"
        size={15}
        color="gold"
        onPress={() => this.filterStrong}
        />
        const component3 = () => <Icon
        name="ios-wine"
        size={15}
        color="gold"

        />

        const buttons = [{ element: component1 }, { element: component2 }, { element: component3 }]
        const { selectedIndex } = this.state
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <Image 
                    style={styles.imageCard} 
                    source={
                            { 
                                uri: 
                                this.state.arrays[0].image
                            }
                        }
                />
                <Text style={styles.title} >
                    {this.state.arrays[0].name}
                </Text>


                <Products 
                    products={this.state.arrays[0].products} 
                    addItemToCart={this.props.addItemToCart} 
                    removeItem={this.props.removeItem}
                />  
                <View style={{
                    justifyContent:'center',
                    width: '100%',
                    padding: 50,
                    paddingTop:20,
                    }}>

                        <Button
                            title="Go to my cart"
                            containerStyle={{ flex: -1 }}
                            buttonStyle={styles.signUpButton}
                            linearGradientProps={{
                            colors: ['#dd016b', '#dd016b'],
                            start: [1, 0],
                            end: [0.2, 0],
                            }}
                            ViewComponent={LinearGradient}
                            titleStyle={styles.signUpButtonText}
                            // onPress={this.createOrder}                                 

                            onPress={
                                () => {
                                this.createOrder
                                this.props.navigation.navigate('Cart', {order : this.state.order});
                            }
                        }
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
      }
    }
const mapDispatchToProps =  {
    addItemToCart,
    removeItem
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (ProductsListView);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width:'100%',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    signUpButtonText: {
        // fontFamily: 'bold',
        fontSize: 13,
    },
    signUpButton: {
        width: 250,
        borderRadius: 50,
        height: 45,
    },
    title: {
        color:'white',
        fontSize:32,
        height: 100,
        position: 'relative',
        backgroundColor: '#00000054',
        width: "100%",
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingTop: 30,

    },
    imageCard:{
        height:100,
        width:'100%',
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    button: {
        padding: 5,
        borderRadius: 25,
        margin: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#DD016B', 
        color: 'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }, 
})
```

I'm trying to navigate to the next screen with the data from I get from my Axios post.

Comment: maybe its typo on the post, maybe not > the this.createOrder is missing parenthesis on your code >> this.createOrder()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the `createOrder` function.

Try this:

```
<Button
    title="Go to my cart"
    containerStyle={{ flex: -1 }}
    buttonStyle={styles.signUpButton}
    linearGradientProps={{
        colors: ["#dd016b", "#dd016b"],
        start: [1, 0],
        end: [0.2, 0]
    }}
    ViewComponent={LinearGradient}
    titleStyle={styles.signUpButtonText}
    // onPress={this.createOrder}

    onPress={this.onGoToMyCartPressed} 
/>;
```

And `onGoToMyCartPressed` would look like:

```
onGoToMyCartPressed = () => {
    this.createOrder(); // <- Call the function
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Cart", { order: this.state.order });
};
```

---

And, if you want to navigate *after* the order has been created, then, have your `createOrder` return the promise, and you can chain off of it in the `onGoToMyCartPressed`

Like so:

```
createOrder() {
    // Return the promise from here
    return axios.post( ApiUrl + 'api/order/post', {
        code: "4f",
        status: "waiting",
        user_name: "salman", 
        user_id: 1,
        club_id: 1,
    }).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            order: response.data,
        });
        console.log('created order',this.state.order)
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error',error);
    })
}
```

And modify the `onGoToMyCartPressed` to use the promise returned.

```
onGoToMyCartPressed = () => {
    // CHange the page once the order has been craeted
    this.createOrder().then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Cart", { order: this.state.order });
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks, did worked `.then()` is like the `wait/async` function?

Comment: Yeah, you can either use `async/await` or `.then()` when dealing with Promises